# Why doesn't my save method work in the admin?

Tags: django, model, save, admin

In my model I overwrite the save-method for my blog model to auto-populate the slug field using the slugify method.

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(BlogCategory)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            # Newly created object, so set slug
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        super(BlogPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But creating a new object in the admin interface doesn't work without either setting the slug field manually or doing something like

```
class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
```

Basically I currently have the same functionality defined twice. Any ideas on how to avoid this? And: why doesn't work my own save method in the admin?

Comment: What "doesn't work" in the admin interface? What happens when you try? What error do you get?

Comment: When I alter my database via the command I leave the slug parameter empty, obviously. If I do the same in the admin I get a "This field is required" error. So I have to slugify it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put `blank=True` in the definition of the `slug` field.

Comment: But why did save work (without `blank=true`) on the command but not in the admin?